# Making so changes to ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have such a data

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(gene = c("14q", "20q", "18q", "4q", "21p", "21q", 
"5q", "22q", "17p", "3p", "9p", "4p", "9q", "19q", "10q", "15q", 
"16p", "19p", "1p", "18p", "16q", "8p"), CNV = c("Deletion", 
"Amplification", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", 
"Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion", "Deletion"), log10_pvalue = c(1.197226275, 
1.88941029, 5.974694135, 5.73754891, 4.995678626, 4.970616222, 
4.793174124, 4.793174124, 4.109020403, 3.524328812, 3.524328812, 
2.823908741, 2.567030709, 2.186419011, 1.769551079, 1.59345982, 
1.59345982, 1.59345982, 1.416801226, 1.195860568, 1.094743951, 
1.087777943), Percentage_altered = c(3000, 5000, 6100, 5300, 
6100, 5600, 4400, 5000, 5000, 4400, 5000, 4700, 3900, 2800, 3300, 
3100, 3300, 3100, 2200, 3600, 3300, 3300), group = c("Responders", 
"Responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", "Non-responders", 
"Non-responders")), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have used this code

```
> p=x %>% 
Warning messages:
1: ggrepel: 6 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
2: ggrepel: 6 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
+     mutate(net_frequency=ifelse(CNV == "Deletion", -Percentage_altered/100, Percentage_altered/100),
+            log10_pvalue = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue)) %>% 
+     ggplot(aes(x = log10_pvalue, y = net_frequency, color = log10_pvalue)) +
+     geom_point(aes(size=Percentage_altered)) +
+     geom_text_repel(aes(label=gene), force=15) +
+     geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2) +
+     scale_color_distiller(type = "div",palette = 5) +
+     theme_classic() +
+     facet_wrap(~group)
> p+xlab("-log10(qvalue)")+ylab("Net frequency of gain and deletion (%)")+theme(
+     plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
+     axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
+     axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold")
+ )+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", 
+                                    size=14),
+         axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", 
+                                    size=14))
```

To plot something like this

[image]

I have some problems here

1- You are seeing here, chromosomal arm size like `1p`, `14q`, whetever are too small too read even color causes some arms are not readable. How I can make the ***text size*** of these elements bigger please ?

2- How I can remove negative sign from Y xis `(60 and 30 instead of -30 and -60)`?

3- How I can change legend titles from `Percentage_altered` to `Frequency altered` and `log10_pvalue` to `-log10(qvalue)` ?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Can you please post "correct" code? `p=x %>%` followed by some warnings is wrong.

Comment: What is `if_else(CNV == "Deletion", log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: While I like @MarBlo's code for improving the `geom_text_repel`, the three questions you asked (text size, label format, and legend title) are all duplicates. I've suggested an answer that addresses these three literal questions, but will mark it as a duplicate in order to promote the value of the existing answers (a preferred thing in "Stack").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `geom_repel_text(..., size = 15)`
2. Write a "labeller" function that uses `abs`.

   **Note**: perhaps you meant to negate all instead of just absolute value? In that case, you can use `` `-` `` instead of `abs`, or you can use `scale_y_reverse`.
3. `scale_*_continuous(name="quux", ...)`

```r
p <- x %>%
  mutate(
    net_frequency = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", -Percentage_altered/100, Percentage_altered/100),
    log10_pvalue = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue) # ??? kept
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log10_pvalue, y = net_frequency, color = log10_pvalue)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Percentage_altered)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = gene), size = 15, force = 15) +
  #                                  ^^^^ 1
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
  #                  ^^^^^^ 2
  scale_color_distiller(name = "-log10(qvalue)", type = "div",palette = 5) +
  #                     ^^^^ 3
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Frequency Altered") +
  #                     ^^^^ 3
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~ group)

p +
  labs(x = "-log10(qvalue)", y = "Net frequency of gain and deletion (%)") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=14),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=14)
  )
```

[image: ggplot2 adjusted]

(You'll need to find an appropriate `size=` for your report media, exaggerated here solely for emphasis.)

Incidentally, Stack's search engine can be tweaked to give informed results.

1. [`[r] ggplot2 text size`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20ggplot2%20text%20size) produced [ggplot geom_text font size control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25061822/3358272)
2. [`[r] ggplot2 axis label format`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+ggplot2+axis+label+format) produced [Custom ggplot2 axis and label formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37662119/3358272)
3. [`[r] ggplot2 legend title`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+ggplot2+legend+title) produced [How to change legend title in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14622421/3358272)

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans, works smartly. As you see in the frequenctly aletred the circles pointing to 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000 while the percntage in my data is from 0 to 100%. How I can edit the circle lables to 30, 40, 50, 60?

Comment: I think the best way would be to change it before sending it to plot, as in `mutate(Percentage_altered=Percentage_altered/100)`, and then you should change your `ifelse(CNV == "Deletion",...)` later to deal with already-reduced data. I think that's far simpler than messing around with labeling and such.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers to your question.

*Although I am not sure why you want to delete the minus-sign on the y-axis.*

For `geom_tex_repel` you may play with `nudge_..` and `overlap` and you should have a look to the phantasmic package vignette [here](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html).

Changes for *scale* and *legend.title* are commented in the code.

Maybe you can respond with the rational behind taking the minus signs out.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

df %>%
  mutate(
    net_frequency = ifelse(CNV == "Deletion",
      -Percentage_altered / 100, Percentage_altered / 100
    ),
    log10_pvalue = if_else(CNV == "Deletion", log10_pvalue, log10_pvalue)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log10_pvalue, y = net_frequency, color = log10_pvalue)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Percentage_altered)) +
  # play with nudge and overlap
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = gene), force = 15, nudge_x = 5, max.overlaps = Inf) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2) +
  scale_color_distiller(type = "div", palette = 5) +
  # here you can change the tick labels
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(-60, 60, 30),
    labels = c("60", "30", "0", "30", "60")
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  # here you can change title of legend
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "Frequency altered")) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: fyi, you applied the `"Frequency altered"` to the wrong scale.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, I have changed it.