# ggplot2 Stacked Bar Chart - Each Bar being 100% and with percenage labels inside each bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

**Background:** I am new to R and ggplot2 and hope to get a simple answer that benefits others in the same situation.

**Question:** What is a simple way in ggplot2 to make **each bar add** up to 100% and displaying **percentage labels** inside each bar?

**Goal:** [What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWTpX.png) (each column totals 100%, with percentage labels inside each column).

**Current Chart:** This is the bar chart I have so far; based on the "mtcars" dataset ([What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxuC1.png)).
Below I have for the "Current Chart":

```
library(ggplot2) # loads ggplot2
data <- mtcars # gets the mtcars dataset

#INFO: A simple barchart with X-axis being Nr of Cylinders, fill color indicating whether or not the car model has an Automatic gearbox..
# ..and Y-axis showing the count of cars by Nr of Cylinders
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_bar() +
  stat_count(geom = "text", 
             aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")), # This row calculates the percentage across all data, adding up to 100%, but I want it to add up to 100% per X-variable (Nr of Cylinders = 4, 6, 8)
             position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") # This row positions the bar percentage level and colors it white.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100

Comment: I think the difference is that I am trying to _add the percentage labels within each chart_ as well.

Comment: For the percentages this might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/in-rs-ggplot2-how-to-add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot-with-percenta

Answer (score 7):

```
library(ggplot2) # loads ggplot2
data <- mtcars 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  stat_count(geom = "text", 
             aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
             position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), colour="white")
```

Your code was almost there, just needed `_fill` instead of `_stack` in position.

[image]

Comment: Almost! Do you know how to make each bar percentage total up to 100%? Example: Currently the leftmost bar is showing 9% and 25% which adds up to a 34% of the plot percent total. Instead I would like that bar to show 26%, 74% with a bar total of 100%.

Comment: Oh I see, I think that you need to get them first, out of the ggplot call, say on a different dataframe, then call it inside the `geom_text`

Comment: I've tried a solution with either `stat_count` or `geom_text` with no success, it seems that you can't group by within this functions..

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late but posting this because I often look for this too... you needed:

```
    # Get labels
    percentData <- mtcars  %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count(am) %>%
    mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
```

to calculate the proportions within each bar and then to plot:

```
    # Plot
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),fill=factor(am)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill")+
    geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio), 
    position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the Bar Percentages within each bar (as in the "Goal" picture attached in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to RLave response:

You can change the axis to show numbers as percentage instead of proportions using the scales package:

```
library(scales) # <- includes scales library
library(ggplot2)
data <- mtcars 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  stat_count(geom = "text", 
             aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
             position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) #          <- set the desired formatting
```