# Ggplot filled barplot with percentage labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I want to make a simple barplot, I have one variable x (A,B,C,D) categorical, another one y (YES, NO) that I am using to fill, and a set of observations, and I want to display a filled barplot, with percentage labels in each column.

Something as simple as like this:

[image: Proper Filled Baplot with %]

So far ggplot layer system has been a nightmare to use. And no solutions I was able to find in already asked questions.

```
x11()
ggplot(data=KS, aes(x=KS$main_category, fill=KS$state)) +
    geom_bar(position="fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count.., group = KS$state), 
              stat = "count")
```

This is what I got so far and a part for positioning it displays the count for every category and state, why can't it display proportions?. And **I want to avoid to manipulate the data** and adding stuff to the dataframe.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: the requested data frame

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

main_category=c('A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D')
state=c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No')
KS = data.frame(main_category, state)
```

Edit 2:

I was able to find my own solution without manipulating the dataset by using implicit ggplot variables:

```
geom_text(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], label=percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]) ),
              stat="count", position=position_fill(0.5), vjust=0.5)
```

Comment: Surely this is at least very similar to questions that have been asked before. You should show what you found searching and explain what is missing in the prior answers.

Comment: Anything that has been asked doesn't refer to counting the observations, but applying percentages based on some preprocessed y axis quantity, which I don't have.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/in-rs-ggplot2-how-to-add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot-with-percenta

Comment: [Please provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) some or all of the data in `KS`. I agree with @42-, many variants of this question have been asked before and I'm sure some combination of existing questions & answers will answer it.

Comment: I have added the KS dataframe.

Comment: I'm intentionally refusing to accept the notion that ggplot activity should be constrained by a request to "avoid manipulating the data", since that is an explicit expectation for users of the ggplot system.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data calculate the precentage first then calculate the respective y-value and plot it as described in the post you linked in the comment:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library(dplyr)

main_category=c('A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','D')
state=c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes','Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No')
KS = data.frame(main_category, state)

cnt <- KS %>% group_by(main_category, state) %>% summarise(n=n())
pcnt <- do.call(rbind,
  lapply(split(cnt, cnt$main_category), function(x){x[x$state=='Yes', 'n']/sum(x$n)})
  )
names(pcnt) <- 'pcnt'
pcnt$main_category <- rownames(pcnt)
pcnt$state='Yes'
pcnt2 <- do.call(rbind,
                lapply(split(cnt, cnt$main_category), function(x){x[x$state=='No', 'n']/sum(x$n)})
)
names(pcnt2) <- 'pcnt'
pcnt2$main_category <- rownames(pcnt2)
pcnt2$state='No'
KS <- merge(KS, rbind(pcnt, pcnt2))

KS$labelpos <- ifelse(KS$state=='Yes',
                      KS$pcnt/2, 1 - KS$pcnt/2)


gg <- ggplot(data=KS, aes(x=main_category, fill=state)) 
gg <- gg + geom_bar(position="fill")
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label = paste0(100*pcnt,"%"),y=labelpos),size = 3)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
print(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so there's no other way than modifying the dataframe? I hoped some internal variables like ..count.. could be used

Comment: Hi Simon, where on the plot does labelpos show up? I guess my question is also what's the logic behind labelpos variable. Thanks!

Comment: I see what the labelpos variable is now after thinking about it. Is there a way to not calculate the y aesthetics and use position = position_fill(vjust = 0.1) as an alternative?