# ggplot2: add labels to percentage plot (not position=fill, but just fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I would like to add percentage labels to a percentage barplot

I found solutions with `position="fill"` ([Add percentage labels to a stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot)) and also here ([How to draw stacked bars in ggplot2 that show percentages based on group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group)), however, I would like to keep relative frequencies for every group.

Here is an example plot:

```r
# library
library(ggplot2)

# data  
df <- data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"),
                   anon=c("yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no"))

# percentage barplot
  ggplot(df, aes(group),fill=anon) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..),fill=anon)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
    ylab("relative frequencies")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now I would like to add percentage labels to each red and green portion of each bar,so that I get "relative-relative" (e.g. 25% for "yes" for group A) values.
How can this be done? Do I have to change my df for this or is this somehow possible within the `ggplot` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to calculate proportion outside of `ggplot2`, here I use `dplyr` for calculating those different proportions:

```r
library(dplyr)

df_calculated <- df %>% count(group, anon) %>%
  mutate(Percent_col = n / sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Percent = n/sum(n))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
  group anon      n Percent_col Percent
  <fct> <fct> <int>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A     no        3       0.333   0.75 
2 A     yes       1       0.111   0.25 
3 B     no        1       0.111   0.333
4 B     yes       2       0.222   0.667
5 C     no        2       0.222   1
```

And then to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` to draw bargraph and `geom_text` to add text label of each proportion:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_calculated, aes(x = group, y = Percent_col, fill = anon))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("relative frequencies")+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Percent)), position = position_stack(0.5))+
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            data = df_calculated %>% 
              group_by(group) %>% 
              summarise(Sum = sum(Percent_col)),
            aes(label = scales::percent(Sum), 
                y = Sum, x = group), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: This solves my question. Just because I am not very familiar with calculating these proportions outside of ggplot, is there a possibility to additionaly add the % of each col on top of each of the cols?

Comment: Do you want the percentage of each group ? (like 44,44 for A, 33,33 for B, 22.22 for C ?) Or do you want the current percentage displayed in bars to be on top of each yes / no cols ?

Comment: The percentage of each group (44,44 for A, 33,33 for B and 22,22 for C)

Comment: Ok, please see my updated answer. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it is great, thanks! Just for my understanding, is it usually better to calculate such measurements outside of `ggplot`?

Comment: You're welcome ;) To my opinion, it is easier to perform calculation outside because it allow you to verify that the calculation is correct. Here especially as you have multiple group to calculate, I would say it is even easier outside of `ggplot2`. But, I think some people prefer to use `..count..` but I'm not very good at it.