# R: show values in geom_bar(position = 'fill')

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following fake data:

```r
n <- 100

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 values = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE) )

df
```

My goal is to have a "filled" barplot as follow, but I don't know how to use `geom_text()` in order to add the values of the percentages for each segment of the bars.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = values, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(??)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
df2 <- as.data.frame(apply(table(df), 2, function(x) x/sum(x)))
df2$grp <- rownames(df2)
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value == 0, "", scales::percent(value))),
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, name = "Percent") +
  labs(x = "Value")
```

[image]

Comment: It should be percentages on the y-axis as well as in the bars

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's perfect now