# R Stacked percentage bar plot with percentage of two factor variables with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, geom-bar

I am trying to plot two factor variables and label the results with % inside the plots.

I already checked this post and the links he/she provides :

[How to center stacked percent barchart labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903368/how-to-center-stacked-percent-barchart-labels?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The ggplot line you are seing here is actually from one of the posts recommended :

```
sex <- c("F","F","M", "M", "M", "F","M","F","F", "M", "M", "M", "M","F","F", "M", "M", "F")
behavior <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A")

BehSex <- data.frame(sex, behavior)

ggplot(BehSex, aes(x= factor(sex), fill= factor(behavior), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
  geom_bar() +
  stat_bin(geom = "text",
          aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
          vjust = 5)
```

However, when I use that line I get the following error :

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is
>   discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

I tried using stat="count" inside the geom_bar() but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Three questions:
1) What am I doing wrong?
2) How can I manage to plot what I want?
3) How can I plot: the % and then in another graph the counts?

Here's the plot that I have right now

[image: Here's the plot that I have right now]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the answer of your post you mentioned, you will have to display the percentage using `position = position_stack()`.

Also, you can use `dplyr` package to get percentage from your dataframe. To my opinion, it makes easier then to display the labeling:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- BehSex %>% group_by(sex) %>% count(behavior) %>% mutate(Percent = n / sum(n)*100)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   sex [2]
  sex   behavior     n Percent
  <fct> <fct>    <int>   <dbl>
1 F     A            2    25  
2 F     B            3    37.5
3 F     C            3    37.5
4 M     A            4    40  
5 M     B            3    30  
6 M     C            3    30
```

Then, you can get your plot like this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = sex, y = Percent, fill = behavior))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Percent,"%"), y = Percent), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Percentage",fill = "Behavior")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome !!! I have been over this for some hours now. Thank you very much ! However, correct me if I am wrong but I think the code you provide overwrites the function df. Moreover, because I had many packages loaded I had to specify dplyr:: before calling count(). Just some precisions for readers. In the end, it worked as expected. 

BehSex2 <- BehSex %>%
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  dplyr::count(behavior) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = n / sum(n)*100)

Comment: `df` will be a new dataframe (of course, if you already have an object called `df` in your environment, it will be replace by this new one but you can name it as you want and as you did with `BehSex2`). If you load the library `dplyr` before running the code, R will use the `count` function from `dplyr` package.

Comment: @dc37 Thanks for your nice answer. Upvoted. Please let me know if possible, how to swich axes (percentage in Y axis and sex in x axis ) as I used the same code for my data and my x axis is year.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach using a bit of data prep with `dplyr`:

EDIT: added counts. To show one or the other just change the label.

```
library(dplyr)
BehSexSum <- BehSex %>%
  count(sex, behavior) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n),
         pct_label = scales::percent(pct))

ggplot(BehSexSum, aes(x= sex, fill = behavior, y = pct)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(pct_label, n, sep = "\n")), 
                lineheight = 0.8,
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jon!! Neat alternative!

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier approach to format the y-axis labels as percentage is using `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`, instead of using `stat_bin(...)`. Therefore, the code can stay almost the same.

```
ggplot(BehSex, aes(x= factor(sex), fill= factor(behavior), y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
  geom_bar() +
  #Set the y axis format as percentage
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  #Change the legend and axes names 
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Percentage",fill = "Behavior")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jonathan! However, correct me if I am wrong but your answer doesn't solve the problem with labels (how to plot the % labels inside the plots). Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my question... My bad!

Comment: Yes, you are right, duh. I forgot to solve the problem with the labels. I think it was clearly stated, but forgot about it. My bad! I think @dc37 has already solved that.